# Azure keyvault value not getting in my code

Tags: c#

I am trying to get keyvault value from azure. I have used below mentioned step to get the key. It was going good upto Crypto but not in KeyVault part.

```
string key = KeyVault.GetValueByKey(Crypto.GetDecryptedValue(WebConfigurationManager.LicenseKey))
```

The Liensekey value I have given as ThumbPrint.

```
public static string GetValueByKey(string key)
{
    string value = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        if (secrets.ContainsKey(key) == false)
        {
            value = KeyVault.GetSecret(key);

            secrets.Add(key, value); //Caching
        }
        else
        {
            value = secrets[key];
        }

    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        new CustomException("Failed to retrieve the value from keyvalult for key:'" + key + "'", Ex);
    }
```

It was failing at `value = KeyVault.GetSecret(key);` step. Can anyone help me in this.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it was failing"? What happens? If an exception is thrown, please include the details of that in your question.